# Авторизация вконтакте Java.

Tags: http, java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте.

Чтобы не костылять, нужно переписать код с PHP-подобного языка AutoIt на Java код авторизации для вконтакте.Переписал,всё так же,но вк возвращает различные ответы.Авторизация полностью автоматическая,от пользователя только логин и пароль нужен.

Код AutoIt,реализован с помощью [WinHTTP через COM-интерфейс](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384106%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) :

```
ConsoleWrite(_VK_API_OAuth("логин","пароль","id приложения",8192)&@CRLF)
Func _VK_API_OAuth($VK_LogIN, $VK_PassWORD, $VK_API_ID, $VK_Scope = 2015231) ; получения Auth_key,функция не моя
    Local $oAuth, $sNewLocation, $sData

    $oRequest = ObjCreate('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1')
    If @error Then
        _VK_API_Error(100)
    EndIf
    $oErrorHandler = ObjEvent('AutoIt.Error', 'ErrorFunc')
    $oRequest.Option(6) = False ;WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects

    $oRequest.Open('GET', 'https://login.vk.com/?act=login&utf8=1&email='&$VK_LogIN&'&pass='&$VK_PassWORD, 0)
        $oRequest.SetRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Testing')
        $oRequest.Send()
        $oRequest.WaitForResponse
    $sNewLocation = $oRequest.GetResponseHeader('Location')
    ConsoleWrite($sNewLocation&@CRLF)
    If Not StringInStr($sNewLocation, 'act=slogin') Then
        $sNewLocation = StringRegExpReplace($sNewLocation, '\?', '$1?act=slogin$2')
        ConsoleWrite($sNewLocation&@CRLF)
        $oRequest.Open('GET', $sNewLocation, 0)
            $oRequest.SetRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Testing')
            $oRequest.Send()
            $oRequest.WaitForResponse
            $sData = $oRequest.ResponseText
            _VK_API_onLogin($sData)
    EndIf
    $oRequest.Open('GET', $sNewLocation, 0)
        $oRequest.SetRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Testing')
        $oRequest.Send()
        $oRequest.WaitForResponse

    $oAuth = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id='&$VK_API_ID&'&redirect_uri=http://api.vk.com/blank.html&scope='&$VK_Scope&'&display=wap&response_type=token'
    $oRequest.Open('GET', $oAuth, 0)
        $oRequest.SetRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Testing')
        $oRequest.Send()
        $oRequest.WaitForResponse
    $sData = $oRequest.ResponseText
    If ($sData <> '') Then

        If StringInStr($sData, 'action=') Then
            $sData = StringRegExp($sData, '.*?action=.?(.*?).?>', 3)
            $sNewLocation = $sData[0]
        Else
            _VK_API_Error('client_id is incorrect')
        EndIf
    Else
        ConsoleWrite($oRequest.GetResponseHeader('Location')&@CRLF)

        $sNewLocation = $oRequest.GetResponseHeader('Location')
    EndIf

    $oRequest.Open('GET', $sNewLocation, 0)
        $oRequest.SetRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Testing')
        $oRequest.Send()
        $oRequest.WaitForResponse
    $sNewLocation = $oRequest.GetResponseHeader('Location')

    $oErrorHandler = 0

    If StringInStr($sNewLocation, 'access_token=') Then
        return __responseParse($sNewLocation)
    Else
        _VK_API_Error(101)
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func _VK_API_Error($sError = '')
    Local $eMSG = ''
    If $sError = '' Then
        If Not IsObj($oRequest) then
            MsgBox(16, 'Error: # 0', 'No object passed to function _VK_API_OAuth')
        Else
            If Not IsArray($sAuth_key) Then
                MsgBox(16, 'Error: # 1', 'Access_token not found')
                Exit
            EndIf
        EndIf
    Else
        Switch $sError
            Case 100
                $eMSG = 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1'
            Case 101
                $eMSG = 'Invalid username/password or account is locked'
            Case 102
                $eMSG = 'Invalid account is locked (captcha needed)'
            Case Else
                If Not IsNumber($sError) Then
                    $eMSG = $sError
                    $sError = ''
                EndIf
        EndSwitch
        If $eMSG Then
            MsgBox(16, 'Error: #'&$sError, 'Error : '&$eMSG)
        EndIf
        $oRequest = False
        Exit
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func _VK_API_onLogin($sData)
    If StringInStr($sData, 'parent.onLoginCaptcha') Then
        $sData = StringRegExpReplace($sData, "(?s).*?onLoginCaptcha\('((?s).*)',.*", '\1')
        _VK_API_Error('onLoginCaptcha (captcha needed)')
    EndIf
EndFunc
Func __responseParse($_sResponse) ; функция для приведения кода в более приятный вид
    $res_array = StringRegExp($_sResponse, '_token=(\w{1,})\&', 3)
    Return $res_array[0]
EndFunc   ;==>__responseParse
```

Мой Java код:

```
 public static void getAPIToken() throws Exception {
    String url = "https://login.vk.com/?act=login&utf8=1&email=" + email + "&pass=" + pass;
    String response = sendHttpsRequest(url, "testing", "Location");
    System.out.println(response);
    response = sendRequest(response, "testing", "");
    response = sendHttpsRequest("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=http://api.vk.com/blank.html&scope=" + scope + "&display=wap&response_type=token", "testing", "");
    if (!response.split("\n\n")[1].equals("")) {
        if (response.split("\n\n")[1].contains("action=")) {
            response = extractPattern(response.split("\n\n")[1], "action=\"(.*?)\"", 0).split("\"")[1];
        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    } else {
        response = extractPattern(response, "https(.*?)&https=1", 0);
    }
    System.out.println(response);
    response = sendHttpsRequest(response, "testing", "");
    //System.out.println(response);
}

public static String sendRequest(String url, String user_agent, String header) throws Exception {
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", user_agent);
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine + "\n");
    }
    in.close();
    String resp = response.toString();
    String buf = "";
    Map<String, List<String>> map = con.getHeaderFields();
    if (header.equals("")) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            buf += entry.getValue() + "\n";
        }
        buf += "\n";
    } else {
        return con.getHeaderField(header);
    }
    return buf + resp;

}

public static String sendHttpsRequest(String url, String user_agent, String header) throws Exception {
    URL urls;
    String resp = "";
    String buf = "";
    try {

        urls = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) urls.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br =
                new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String input;
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
            resp += input + "\n";
        }
        br.close();

        Map<String, List<String>> map = con.getHeaderFields();
        if (header.equals("")) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                buf += entry.getValue() + "\n";
            }
            buf += "\n";
        } else {
            return con.getHeaderField(header);
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println();
    }
    return buf + resp;
}
```

Есть некоторая разница,я не переписывал ту часть кода,куда при использовании моего аккаунта функция не заходит.То есть один из if'ов.

Так вот,я не знаю в чём проблема,но предполагаю что в AutoIt сохраняются куки,а я нет.

Как можно исправить ситуацию?